# Save a table in ascending order in order to avoid overlapping proportional circles (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, sorting

Is there a quick way to sort an attribute table in QGIS in ascending order permanently and save it? When you make a map with proportional circles in QGIS the circles overlaps between each other according to their sorting order. I want the smaller circle above the bigger which is why I think sorting can solve this issue.

Note: If I click on the header, the table will be sorted in ascending order using the clicked column. However, if I save it that way and I open it again nothing has changed about row order.

Comment: @ChrisW, the post you reference relates to ArcGIS

Comment: @Aaron Note while that question *body* says ArcMap, there is a QGIS solution or two there. There is also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135892/ which is more specific to ArcGIS but gives some general information on why doing this doesn't necessarily make sense.

Comment: I think that make sense in my case. When you make a map with proportional circles in QGIS the circles overlaps between each other according to their sorting order. I want the smaller circle above the bigger that's why I need to sort it permanently

Comment: As Vince's answer at the ArcGIS specific question I linked to points out, there is no guarantee that the drawing order will relate to the record order. It is *typically* last drawn/higher record number on top, and you will probably get what you want by doing the sort (it is a common workaround/solution), just be aware it isn't a guarantee. The MMQGIS plugin underdark mentions or the GDAL solution Mike T presents in the duplicate link should do what you want. @Aaron Maybe migrate the two non-Arc answers from that other question here? Or is it too late to do that?

Comment: I just tried it out. That's working. Smaller circles are above the biggers.

Comment: @ChrisW Migrating answers from other posts is not an an available action on GIS SE.

Comment: @Aaron Ah, I must be thinking of when questions are merged (which wouldn't be applicable here). A quick search on Meta turned up nothing as well, though the issue has been raised. Thanks for checking.

Comment: Since the other thread already contained different solutions, I now made the question text more generic in order to have one central thread (covering different platforms) for this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, that is a very easy treatment with the MMQGIS plugin (Quantum GIS Plugin Repository). It allows to rewrite on another table using selected column and chosen order.

[image]

It also works for the circles problem

[image]