# ArcGIS - possible to set the drawing order of polygon features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, symbology, map-drawing, draw-order

I have a table with polygons that I wish to display in a map. I would like the smaller polygons to appear on top of larger polygons. Is there a way to set the drawing order such that  the larger polygon outlines don't cover up the smaller ones?

I've tried using the polygon area attribute as a transparency factor within the layer's symbology properties - but this is not working well enough.

Comment: Does esri know about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you already have a field carrying the area, just use the [Sort](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/sort.htm) tool, and use the area field with the 'DESCENDING' option.

**Note: The Sort tool requires an advanced license.**

Comment: @val Note this method is not *guaranteed* to always draw the small shapes on top of the large ones. It also has other performance implications - see Vince's answer at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135892/

Comment: If you edit the data and add features, then a Sort is needed. So this isn't the always true method. Normally, the features will be drawn in the order that they are returned from the database/file. I thinks Ian answer is the correct one here. like this post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94781/what-dictates-the-drawing-order-of-overlapping-features-with-in-the-same-layer-f

Answer (score 14):

You could add a new field called `Size`, and then field calc either `Small` or `Large` into the new field.

Then symbolize by Unique Values based on the Size field. Then go into `Advanced --> Symbol Levels` and make sure the `Draw this layer using symbol levels specified below` is checked, and that the Small label is above the Large label.

However you choose to do it, what you're looking for is the Symbol Levels option.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If these are gdb feature classes, another option would be to use a Definition Query that is based on the SHAPE_AREA field.  Just right-click on the layer in the TOC and copy and paste it.  Place the new layer on top of the old layer, and in the new layer add a definition query that will filter out any features that are bigger than ____.  Now you have the smaller features on top of the larger features.

Comment: Thx but there are way too many features for this method (>1000)