# Layering grid codes visually

Tags: arcmap, shapefile

Is it possible to order grid codes in a shapefile visually by building a query in ArcMap?  For example in symbology I have grid codes 1, 2, 4, 5 in a shapefile and I want to make it so that when the symbology is displayed on the map itself, grid code 2 is always onto grid code four.

I can currently make grid code 4 go away by 
"gridcode" = 1 OR "gridcode" = 2 OR "gridcode" = 5

But I want to maintain grid code 4, and if it over laps grid code 2 I want grid code 2 to be on top of grid code 4 when I am visually looking at the map

I'm using the most recent version of ArcMap.

Ordering the grid codes and applying it in symbology currently does not solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried with [Symbol Levels](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272762/arcmap-how-to-set-drawing-order-for-points-displayed-by-multiple-attributes)? You can set the drawing order (priority) of each category of features with Symbol Levels.

Comment: the shape file is set to unique values many fields, value fields set to grid code, grid code id's are 1,2,4,5.  within the symbology tab in properties I can move them up and down with the arrows on the right side (is this what you mean by symbol levels).    no mater what sequence they are in it does not effect how they are displayed on the map currently.

Comment: YES THAT SOLVE THE PROBLEM, THANKS